# How do you visually update a select2 widget?

Tags: select2

I'm trying to select the value of a select2 widget using js. I can change the value ok:

```
jQuery('#excludeGroups').val("846").trigger("change");
```

The problem I'm having is that this doesn't update the display. It *does* work in that when you submit the form it's the correct value - so it's working behind the scenes. But it doesn't actually change the display - the new value doesn't *appear* in the widget. The documentation suggests trigger("change") should do it. I'm not getting any console errors. Is there a trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out. I needed to wrap my jQuery code in:

```
CRM.$(function($) {

});
```

The change trigger - and other select2 events - started working once I did this.

Comment: Wow. i wish I had learned this months ago, this would have saved me so much pain and suffering!

Comment: This same fix also applies this other way around: listening to the change event. Thanks!